# Bootstrap - horizontally centering input group within form group

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble centering my input groups within my form. Any help would be appreciate. My best guess is it's something with the input group div, not interacting with the form group as anticipated. The header and button center, just not the inputs, as seen in the codepen below. Thanks!

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Torymae/pen/OJMoYRM

```
<div class="col-8 change-password-view mx-auto">
  <form id="change-password" class="form-group">
    <h4>Change Password</h4>
      <br />
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend2">
              <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-key" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 8a4 4 0 0 1 7.465-2H14a.5.5 0 0 1 .354.146l1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L13 9.207l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L11 9.207l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L9 9.207l-.646.647A.5.5 0 0 1 8 10h-.535A4 4 0 0 1 0 8zm4-3a3 3 0 1 0 2.712 4.285A.5.5 0 0 1 7.163 9h.63l.853-.854a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.646-.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.646-.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.793-.793-1-1h-6.63a.5.5 0 0 1-.451-.285A3 3 0 0 0 4 5z"/>
                <path d="M4 8a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0z"/>
              </svg>
            </span>
            <input type="password" name="passwords[old]" placeholder="Current Password" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br />
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
             <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend2">
              <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-key" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
               <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 8a4 4 0 0 1 7.465-2H14a.5.5 0 0 1 .354.146l1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L13 9.207l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L11 9.207l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L9 9.207l-.646.647A.5.5 0 0 1 8 10h-.535A4 4 0 0 1 0 8zm4-3a3 3 0 1 0 2.712 4.285A.5.5 0 0 1 7.163 9h.63l.853-.854a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.646-.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.646-.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.793-.793-1-1h-6.63a.5.5 0 0 1-.451-.285A3 3 0 0 0 4 5z"/>
               <path d="M4 8a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0z"/>
              </svg>
             </span>
             <input type="password" name="passwords[new]" placeholder="New Password" required>
           </div>
         </div>
        <br />
        <button class="btn primary-btn">Change Password</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<div class="container-fluid">  
  <div class="col-8 change-password-view mx-auto">
    <form id="change-password" class="form-group">
      <h4>Change Password</h4>
      <br />
        <div class="input-group justify-content-center">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend2">
              <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-key" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
               <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 8a4 4 0 0 1 7.465-2H14a.5.5 0 0 1 .354.146l1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L13 9.207l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L11 9.207l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L9 9.207l-.646.647A.5.5 0 0 1 8 10h-.535A4 4 0 0 1 0 8zm4-3a3 3 0 1 0 2.712 4.285A.5.5 0 0 1 7.163 9h.63l.853-.854a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.646-.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.646-.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.793-.793-1-1h-6.63a.5.5 0 0 1-.451-.285A3 3 0 0 0 4 5z"/>
               <path d="M4 8a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0z"/>
              </svg>
            </span>
            <input type="password" name="passwords[old]" placeholder="Current Password" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="input-group justify-content-center">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend2">
              <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-key" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 8a4 4 0 0 1 7.465-2H14a.5.5 0 0 1 .354.146l1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L13 9.207l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L11 9.207l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L9 9.207l-.646.647A.5.5 0 0 1 8 10h-.535A4 4 0 0 1 0 8zm4-3a3 3 0 1 0 2.712 4.285A.5.5 0 0 1 7.163 9h.63l.853-.854a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.646-.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.646-.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.793-.793-1-1h-6.63a.5.5 0 0 1-.451-.285A3 3 0 0 0 4 5z"/>
                <path d="M4 8a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0z"/>
              </svg>
            </span>
            <input type="password" name="passwords[new]" placeholder="New Password" required>
           </div>
         </div>
       <br />
       <button class="btn primary-btn">Change Password</button>
     </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @abdulrahman! Please consider improving your answer by adding some clarification on what you changed, and why.

Comment: I just add  justify-content-center this class in bootstrap
to make any tag center

Comment: @Abdulrahman Hi, I saw your code well. But when I run the code, it seems to be stuck on the left now. I think need to fix this.

Comment: my answer it'is the same his answer 
but I'm using bootstrap class but he right it from zero why?
It is already in bootstrap

Comment: see this page 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/#justify-content

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

I have referenced some of your source code. Some style codes are different. Focused on centering the `input` tag rather than attributes like `border`.

**-HTML-**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
      <form>
        <h4>Change password</h4>
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span id="inputGroupPrepend2" class="input-group-text">
              <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-key" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 8a4 4 0 0 1 7.465-2H14a.5.5 0 0 1 .354.146l1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L13 9.207l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L11 9.207l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L9 9.207l-.646.647A.5.5 0 0 1 8 10h-.535A4 4 0 0 1 0 8zm4-3a3 3 0 1 0 2.712 4.285A.5.5 0 0 1 7.163 9h.63l.853-.854a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.646-.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.646-.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.793-.793-1-1h-6.63a.5.5 0 0 1-.451-.285A3 3 0 0 0 4 5z"/>
                  <path d="M4 8a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0z"/>
                </svg>
            </span>
            <input type="password" name="passwords[old]" placeholder="Current Password" required/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span id="inputGroupPrepend2" class="input-group-text">
              <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-key" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                 <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 8a4 4 0 0 1 7.465-2H14a.5.5 0 0 1 .354.146l1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L13 9.207l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L11 9.207l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L9 9.207l-.646.647A.5.5 0 0 1 8 10h-.535A4 4 0 0 1 0 8zm4-3a3 3 0 1 0 2.712 4.285A.5.5 0 0 1 7.163 9h.63l.853-.854a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.646-.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.646-.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.793-.793-1-1h-6.63a.5.5 0 0 1-.451-.285A3 3 0 0 0 4 5z"/>
                 <path d="M4 8a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0z"/>
                </svg>
            </span>
            <input type="password" name="passwords[new]" placeholder="New Password" required/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn primary-btn">Change Password</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**-CSS-**

```
form, h4 {
   text-align: center;
}

h4 {
   margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.row, .input-group {
   justify-content: center;
}

.input-group {
   display: flex;
   margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

**-Result-**

[image]